# How to Tuning Apache and Mysql

Tags: mysql, apache

```
top - 12:24:22 up 1 day, 18:37,  2 users,  load average: 1.19, 1.77, 1.59
Tasks: 166 total,   4 running, 162 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 20.1%us,  5.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 62.4%id, 10.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    987780k total,   979052k used,     8728k free,    17240k buffers
Swap:  2104432k total,   106760k used,  1997672k free,   174100k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 4116 mysql     15   0  356m 105m 4176 S 12.0 11.0 139:58.69 mysqld
 5722 apache    15   0  160m  17m 4224 S 10.0  1.8   0:00.78 httpd
 5741 apache    15   0  161m  17m 4220 S  9.3  1.8   0:00.37 httpd
 5840 apache    15   0  161m  17m 4148 S  8.3  1.8   0:00.52 httpd
 5846 apache    15   0  161m  17m 4132 S  6.3  1.8   0:00.47 httpd
 5744 apache    15   0  162m  18m 4224 S  2.0  1.9   0:00.37 httpd
 5725 apache    15   0  161m  17m 4424 S  1.3  1.8   0:00.34 httpd
 5755 apache    15   0  105m  14m 4248 R  1.3  1.5   0:00.17 httpd
 5564 apache    15   0  163m  19m 4360 S  1.0  2.0   0:00.65 httpd
 5322 apache    16   0  162m  19m 4456 S  0.7  2.0   0:02.26 httpd
 5586 apache    15   0  161m  18m 4468 S  0.7  1.9   0:01.77 httpd
 5852 apache    16   0 99.9m  11m 3424 S  0.7  1.2   0:00.02 httpd
 5121 root      18   0 98.3m  10m 4320 S  0.3  1.1   0:00.07 httpd
 5723 apache    15   0  161m  17m 4240 S  0.3  1.8   0:00.31 httpd
 5833 apeadm    15   0 12740 1128  808 R  0.3  0.1   0:00.03 top
 5834 apache    15   0  160m  16m 4172 S  0.3  1.7   0:00.20 httpd
 5836 apache    15   0 98.5m 9388 2912 S  0.3  1.0   0:00.01 httpd
    1 root      15   0 10348  592  560 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.72 init
    2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/0
```

Server Spec:
 CENTOS CPU:E5200 RAM:1G
Software: Zencart X 3, Piwik x1

Server always down,How to tuning apache and mysql?

Thanks a lot.

`httpd.conf`

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          8
    MinSpareServers       8
    MaxSpareServers      15
    ServerLimit         450
    MaxClients          450
    MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>


<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    ServerLimit         450
    MaxClients          450
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_beos_module>
    StartThreads            10
    MaxClients              50
    MaxRequestsPerThread 10000
</IfModule>


<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    ThreadStackSize      65536
    StartThreads           250
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    MaxThreads            1000
    MaxRequestsPerChild      10000
    MaxMemFree             100
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_mpmt_os2_module>
    StartServers           2
    MinSpareThreads        5
    MaxSpareThreads       10
    MaxRequestsPerChild    10000
</IfModule>
```

`my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
set-variable = query_cache_limit=1M
set-variable = query_cache_size=16M
set-variable = query_cache_type=1
set-variable =  max_connections=400
set-variable = interactive_timeout=100
set-variable = wait_timeout=100
set-variable = connect_timeout=100
set-variable = thread_cache_size=16
#
# Set key_buffer to 5 - 50% of your RAM depending on how much
# you use MyISAM tables, but keep key_buffer_size + InnoDB
# buffer pool size < 80% of your RAM
set-variable = key_buffer=32M
set-variable = join_buffer=1M
set-variable = max_allowed_packet=8M
set-variable = table_cache=1024
set-variable = record_buffer=1M
set-variable = sort_buffer_size=2M
set-variable = read_buffer_size=2M
set-variable = max_connect_errors=10
set-variable = myisam_sort_buffer_size=16M

#Useful for SMP
set-variable = thread_concurrency=8
```

Comment: There is no magic configuration that works perfectly for any possible case. The optimization methods depend on a **lot** of factors. Better find some optimization guru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Server always down,How to tuning apache and mysql?

eh? If its always down how did you get those figures? Tuning isn't going to fix stability issues.

A short answer to how to tune Apache and mysql would fill a large book. Here's some links to books on MysQL: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,92131,92131

And for Apache try [searching on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=Apache%20performance&x=0&y=0#/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n:283155,k%3aApache%20performance&page=2&keywords=Apache%20performance&ie=UTF8&qid=1302252320).

Also, you've not provded any information about what's running in between Apache and MySQL - understanding what's going on here is pretty critical too - as is understanding how to improve HTTP and browser performance (caching, keepalives, compression, javascript....).